# Django show multiple pictures of an item in HTML

Tags: django

I can add pictures to my admin page but I want to figure out how to display them all on my main html page. Below code shows only the first image that I uploaded to the admin page and ignores the rest.

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    PN = models.CharField(max_length=100,
    image = models.FileField(blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class PostImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Product, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.FileField(upload_to = 'products/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.name
```

views.py

```
from .models import Product, PostImage
def product_detail(request, PN):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, PN=PN, available=True)
    photos = PostImage.objects.filter(product=product)
    return render(request, 'product/product_detail.html', {'product':product, 'photos':photos})
```

product_detail.html

```
{% block content %}
     {% for obj in object %}
        <div id="item">
          {% for image in obj.postimage_set.all %}
            <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }} {{ obj.image.url }}" />
          {% endfor %}
         </div>
     {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: `<img src="{{ obj.image.url }}" />`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I tried that but only shows the picture from product five times and nothing from PostImage. I want to be able to view images from PostImage. I added five different photos to the item and I want to be able to view them all. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The `PostImage` objects use `image` as iterator, so you use:

```
{% block content %}
     {% for obj in object %}
        <div id="item">
          {% for image in obj.postimage_set.all %}
            <img src="{{ image.images.url }}" />
          {% endfor %}
         </div>
     {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I tried that too it shows five empty blocks (no image)

Comment: @Did you use `.images` (with `s`, although this is an *odd* naming convention) as field? What does it specifies as `src=""`?

Comment: @user8607309: note that not only the `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` is removed, it uses `{{ image.images.url }}` as variable, not `{{ obj.image.url }}`.